# Herança de método CompareTo em classe genérica

Tags: java, genéricos

Estou a implementar uma classe Node em que queria que o método equals e compareTo fosse herdado do tipo T, no entanto não estou a conseguir.
Se fizer a declaração assim

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparable <Node<T>>
```

E fizer o Override dos métodos como mostro a seguir funciona

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object e) {
    Node<T> aux = (Node<T>) e;
    if (this.value.equals(aux.getValue()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

 @Override
public int compareTo(Node<T> a) {
    int res = this.value.compareTo(a.getValue());
    return res;
}
```

No entanto a ideia que tenho é que fazendo a seguinte declaração que esta classe ia herdar o Comparable do tipo T

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Conseguem me explicar o que estou a fazer mal e o porque de funcionar com a primeira declaração mas não com a última?

Testei esta última declaração criando Node e tentando comparar mas não funciona, para dois nós com a mesma String dá me que é falso, mas eu sei que o tipo String implementa a interface Comparable, pelo que acho que não está a herdar os métodos.

Como fiz a comparação foi assim

```
Node<String> a = new Node<String("1234");
Node<String> b = new Node<String("1234");
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

O output dá falso

Obrigado

Comment: você tá chamando o compareTo a partir de onde? Essa sua segunda definição ali só quer dizer que o genérico que você espera extende um comparable, já a primeira diz isso e que também implementa o comparable, ou seja, você poderia passar inclusive o próprio node

Comment: Eu estou a chamar o compareTo no meu main, apenas criei dois Node<String> com a mesma String e vi se eram iguais, o que deu falso. No entanto se fizer Override do compareTo na classe Node já dá certo. O que eu queria era não ter de fazer Override do compareTo na classe Node e herdar esse Override do tipo que for usado no Node

Comment: Pelo que eu percebi, se usar a primeira definição posso comparar dois Node diretamente porque implemento o método para fazer a comparação, se usar a segunda declaração não posso comparar dois Node diretamente, apenas posso comparar o tipo T que foi passado, é isto?

Comment: não, o equals que você pegou no exemplo está vindo de object, não do comparable da string, a segunda declaração só está informando o que você espera receber ni seu genérico, nada além disso

Comment: Não tem como "herdar os métodos do tipo T". Se quer comparar Nodes, precisa sobrescrever o `equals` e `compareTo` na classe `Node`. Se vc não sobrescreve, eles são herdados de `Object` (e o `equals` de `Object` compara se os objetos são a mesma instância, por isso retorna `false` se vc não sobrescrever)

Comment: Obrigado LucasMiranda e hkotsubo já percebi. Eu estava a tentar fazer algo que não é possível, por alguma razão achei que desse.